# Hazelcast :: Configure for only one host with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, hazelcast

Now, I am working with spring mvc and hazel cast.

Everything is working well with my application.

For better performance, we would like to use caching method.

We can't use `EhCache` because we have 2 application in same server with single database.

So, we shifted to `Hazelcast` and we already configure and it is working.

We got what we want but the problem is hazelcast looking for other server and other server can join our server in caching process.

That is the problem.

> We would like to use hazelcast for only one server and no incoming request and outgoing request to join on multicast.

We only want to share data only in our one server.

But we can't find the right configuration for it.

Our current config is as shown below:

**In Java Config**

```
Config config = new Config("instance");

NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();

JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();

join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
```

**In spring-application-context.xml**

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="instance"/>
</bean> 

<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

Caching is working well with the above codes but it join multiple server.

Please, help me to configure it for only one server, no external join.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multicast is the only discovery mechanism enabled by default, so turning it off should be all that's required to stop this server joining others.

In `spring-application-context.xml` try

```
    <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
            <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="false">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>
```

The Java config looks good too, but I don't see where it's used.

As proof also, change the group name to something other than "*dev*". "*dev*" is the default, so if you use a different name temporarily and you see the new name in the logs, you know your configuration is being used.

Comment: Thanks, i will test and will ask you if any others. we just use java for prevent join to others and to me from other. I think, it is not working. And we will change group name ASAP.

Comment: I can't start my second application. it show error `Port [5701] is already in use and auto-increment is disabled. Hazelcast cannot start.` Is any other different config for different application for same server. thanks

Comment: how can we prevent joining other server to our server. Is off to multicast is enough?

Comment: can i set maximun no of member for cluster?

Comment: You can set the `name` in the `hz:group` section. Only processes with a matching name can join together. However this won't place an upper limit on how many can be in group, since Hazelcast is intended to be scalable.

Comment: So perhaps you could set the group's name to the hostname. Then only processes from that host could join. It's not an invincible approach, but it might do what you need

Comment: we will try this later...now...we got by enable `tcp-ip` and add localhost to member. I think that is working what we need. I will post my answer and pls check.

Comment: my question is, if we not add in member list, that host can't join or not? can you explain me?

Comment: The member list is for outbound probing, not inbound probing. StackOverflow is advising me long discussions should become separate questions.